# When we install a operating system, can we plugin a ghost file?

Tags: installation, iso-image, ghost

When we install a operating system, can we plugin a ghost file?

In general, we install a OS, we plugin a `.iso` file, then install it.

but I have a question, if I use a Windows Server 2008 iso file, after I install it, I will enter the system then configure many things. it is troublesome if I install a lot many count.

So, whether I can convert the system out to a ghost file, then when install OS I plugin the ghost file?

What's the difference between them? and install a `.iso` file whether is just extract the `.iso` file's content to a special place (a partition).

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean, in my current Windows OS, it is configured perfect, whether I can make my current OS to a `.iso` file(if possible) or a `ghost` file out to a device, then when I install other host, I want to use the file as the installation file.

my scenario is physical hosts, not virtual machine.

Comment: I think (the question isn't very clear) what you're asking for is, can you clone an existing Windows install to an ISO image/ghost file which can then be restored onto another hard disk for another PC? Please clarify.

Comment: It depends on what you are doeing. For exemple when installing virtual machines it is more convenient to install once then duplicate the VMs. So all of them keep same configuration. It is also possible to clone a physical hdd after install adn config but only when all target devices have the same hardware.... What is your scenario?